# Программа на Java для считывания и аккумулирования результата

Tags: java

Каким образом реализовать програмку на Java, для считывания текстового файлика. Пример такой, имеется файлик где в один столбик написаны имена например Еда, Машина, Прочие расходы и тд, а вторым столбиком сумма которая была потрачена в течении месяца. Нужно реализовать простую программу которой я вскормлю этот файлик и она посчитает все автоматически сколько расходов за месяц у меня было. Логика программы условна, так как я учусь писать что то сложнее Хелло Верлда. Так вот, объясните как реализовать данный функционал. Не нужно решений, просто как реализовать )

Answer (score 2):

1. Читать файл в цикле построчно
2. На каждой итерации цикла разбивать полученную строку на колонки
3. Преобразовывать вторую колонку в `int`
4. Суммировать результат преобразования с предварительно объявленной
   переменной